# Properly add types for React Navigation Nested Stack v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I'm migrating from `react-navigation v5` to `v6` I'm trying to add type checking and I encouraged a problem that couldn't find a solution from the docs

```js
    import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    
    export type RootStackParamList = {
      Home: StackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList>;
      Users: StackScreenProps<UsersStackParamList>;
      //other stacks that I have
    };
    
    export type HomeStackParamList = {
      Home: undefined;
      Bets: { id: string };
    }
    
    export type UsersStackParamList = {
      Profile: undefined;
      ProfileCreate: undefined;
    };
    
    //get global type safety I'm using this as recommended in docs
    declare global {
      namespace ReactNavigation {
        interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
      }
    }
```

The problem arises when I try to use the `useNavigation()` hook
let's say I want to navigate from the `Home` Component to the `Users ProfilCreate` as below

```js
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    
    //as I understood it should work like this
    navigation.navigate('Users',{screen:'ProfileCreate'})
```

But the problem is I can't use `{screen:'ProfileCreate'}` here it allows me to pass this object.

Even if i use the navigate as below with the intialRouteName

```js
     navigation.navigate('Users');
```

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: StackScreenProps | undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: "Users"; key?: string | undefined; params: StackScreenProps<...>; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }'.

Please note that I'm using the `Stack` navigation, not the `NativeStack` navigation.

I have another question. Suppose we have a stack with routes(ex:`SomeStackParamList`) that do not contain any parameters. Even if there are no parameters, do we still need to add them to the RootStackParamList to receive type suggestions at the global level?

```
export type SomeStackParamList = {
   OneRote: undefined;
   TwoRoute: undefined;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your types are incorrect. `StackScreenProps` shouldn't be used like that. You need to use `NavigatorScreenParams`:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamList>;
  Users: NavigatorScreenParams<UsersStackParamList>;
  //other stacks that I have
};
```

Please follow the docs for TypeScript setup https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#nesting-navigators